# Gulp command doent work properly

Tags: node.js, windows, gulp, hpc

I have strange issue with gulp on Windows. I did

```
npm rm -g gulp-cli
npm rm -g gulp
npm install -g gulp-cli
npm install -g gulp
```

And when I type

```
gulp
```

I see

```
Node Commands

Syntax:
    node {operator} [options] [arguments]
```

I dont understand whats going on.

Other machine works just fine - gulp command anywhere 'local gulp not found', and under a project it works with gulpfile.js as expected. But here I see something like 'Node: i dont know any gulp, here is my manual'

UPD:
According to answer @DavidR2016 , I took a look to the PATH and HPC were there. 
I didnt want to break anything so put

```
;C:\Program Files\Microsoft HPC Pack 2012\Bin\;
```

To the end of the path and it works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you have added your node to PATH in the environment variables. if so you may have something called [Microsoft HPC Pack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853440%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) installed which also has a node.exe file that could be conflicting. So make sure you have the correct one in PATH.

Comment: lifesaver! I think I shoud add HPC tag